# React useState infinite rerender

Tags: reactjs

a simple snippet like this, causes an infinite loop. How can I use a props that decides whether the state should be updated if this approach apparently doesnt work?

```
import React from "react";

export default function Igor_test(props) {

  const { update_name } = props;
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: 'Joe',
    age: 15,
  });

  if (update_name) {
    setValues(oldValues =>({
      ...oldValues,
      [values.name]: 'Pat',
    }))
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <p>
        {values.name}
      </p>
    </div>
  )

}
```

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
>   prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: The question is what does “update_name” returns each time. Cause if it always has a truthy value you get an infinite loop since you fire setValues (which causes a rerender)

Comment: Also `[values.name]: 'Pat'` seems suspicious.

Comment: update_name, in reality comes either as null or an Object - if it's the object, I would like to update the state (once).
A very similar approach with a class based component, seems to be working rather well.

Comment: Hi Bishonen_PL, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of your `if` condition,

```
if (update_name) {
    setValues(oldValues =>({
      ...oldValues,
      [values.name]: 'Pat',
    }))
}
```

Here `if` condition is setting state, then your component re-render. When your component re-renders it will again checking the `if` condition and finds value for `update_name` and again setting state and so on...

**This causing infinite loop.**

There is one more issue in your `setValues`, you are trying to set `[values.name]` which is wrong, it should be simply `name`.

What you need is `useEffect` hook with dependency array, which will keep track of supplied parameter and reacts when that parameter changes.

Now whenever `update_name` changes, it will check if it has value and set state accordingly.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (update_name) {
    setValues(oldValues =>({
      ...oldValues,
      name: 'Pat',     //ideally instead of hard coding new name you should use `update_name` passed as props.
    }))
  }
},[update_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your logic inside a `useEffect hook` to control when to update the state
be aware that this function **will** **be rerender every time the `update_name` changes**.

```
React.useEffect( () => {
    setValues(oldValues =>({
      ...oldValues,
      name: 'Pat',
    }))
},[update_name]);
```